# ng-repeat link highlight: change css for selected links only and reset the rest

Tags: angularjs

I have links/buttons within ng-repeat derective. It is easy to highlight a link once clicked/selected but I can not figure out how to un-highlight the previously selected link upon selection the next one.

Say link 1 is selected and colored red then when I select link 2 I want to bring link 1 to its normal color. All my attempts end up with "shift" effect: all links are highlighted.

I understand the ng-repeat dedicated scope issue though.

So once a link is clicked I need to reset all the links to the oroginal color and then set just the selected one. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are these toggle buttons? Consider using [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#buttons)

Comment: Many ways to do this. You should show the code you have so far. `ng-class` can easily solve your problem.